# how to configure soap lite client to consuming a WCF service with wshttpbinding?

Tags: wcf, soap, soapui, soaplite

I have a soap lite client consuming a wcf service.  I tested everything on basichttpbinding and it works fine.  When I switch the binding to wshttpbinding:

```
<endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="customWsBinding"
          contract="LogisticServiceLibrary.ILogisticService" />
```

and changed the soap lite version to use 1.2:

```
$client = SOAP::Lite
        ->proxy($endpoint)
    ->soapversion('1.2');
```

then it gives me an error and below is the output from SOAPUI:

> Wed Nov 30 18:36:14 EST 2011:DEBUG:>> "POST /LogisticService
>   HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]" Wed Nov 30 18:36:14 EST 2011:DEBUG:>> "TE:
>   deflate,gzip;q=0.3[\r][\n]" Wed Nov 30 18:36:14 EST 2011:DEBUG:>>
>   "Connection: TE, close[\r][\n]" Wed Nov 30 18:36:14 EST 2011:DEBUG:>>
>   "Accept: text/xml[\r][\n]" Wed Nov 30 18:36:14 EST 2011:DEBUG:>>
>   "Accept: multipart/*[\r][\n]" Wed Nov 30 18:36:14 EST 2011:DEBUG:>>
>   "Accept: application/soap[\r][\n]" Wed Nov 30 18:36:14 EST
>   2011:DEBUG:>> "User-Agent: SOAP::Lite/Perl/0.712[\r][\n]" Wed Nov 30
>   18:36:14 EST 2011:DEBUG:>> "Content-Length: 49496[\r][\n]" Wed Nov 30
>   18:36:14 EST 2011:DEBUG:>> "Content-Type: application/soap+xml;
>   charset=utf-8[\r][\n]" Wed Nov 30 18:36:14 EST 2011:DEBUG:>>
>   "SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/ILogisticService/IssueOrder[\r][\n]"
>   Wed Nov 30 18:36:14 EST 2011:DEBUG:>> "Host: localhost:8008[\r][\n]"
>   Wed Nov 30 18:36:14 EST 2011:DEBUG:>> "[\r][\n]" Wed Nov 30 18:36:14
>   EST 2011:DEBUG:>> "
>   xmlns:namesp1="http://namespaces.soaplite.com/perl"
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
>   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>   soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
>   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
>   xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
>   xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns=""
>   xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LogisticServiceLibrary"
>   Wed Nov 30 18:36:14 EST 2011:DEBUG:<< "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad
>   Request[\r][\n]" Wed Nov 30 18:36:14 EST 2011:DEBUG:<< "HTTP/1.1 400
>   Bad Request[\r][\n]" Wed Nov 30 18:36:14 EST 2011:DEBUG:<<
>   "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]" Wed Nov 30 18:36:14 EST 2011:DEBUG:<<
>   "Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/1.0[\r][\n]" Wed Nov 30 18:36:14 EST
>   2011:DEBUG:<< "Date: Wed, 30 Nov 2011 23:36:14 GMT[\r][\n]" Wed Nov 30
>   18:36:14 EST 2011:DEBUG:<< "[\r][\n]"

It says 400 Bad Request...  Any idea what's going on?

Comment: I have gotten past that point now after reading this: [link](http://www.herongyang.com/Web-Services/Perl-SOAP-1-2-soapversion-and-envprefix-Methods.html) now another problem occures.  Has anyone actually configured soap lite to work with wshttpbinding before?

Answer (score 2):

Using `WSHttpBinding` requires that the client speak SOAP 1.2 and also understand ws-addressing, ws-reliablemessaging, ws-security, ws-policy and ws-policyassertion. I doubt SOAP::Lite understands any of that, hence the "Lite" nomenclature. `BasicHttpBinding` is pretty basic, just like SOAP::Lite :)